# Blazor Server Component not refreshing after state change

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am rendering a component within another component based on some ifs, logic is that there are clients and they have linked clients, if there are any linked clients then a dropdown is shown, and if user selects any linked client from the dropdown, the linked client data will be shown side by side in the same component.

**But the problem is that it works for the first time when I select a linked client, if I select another, component doesn't refresh, if I change it to 0 then it again refreshes and only shows the client data, and then if I change it again from 0 it works again.**

below is my code.

```
@if (LinkedClients?.Count() > 0)
{
    <select class="form-control input-width-auto bg-white" @onchange="e => ChangeLinkedClient(e)">
        <option value="0">Select Linked Account</option>
        @foreach (var item in LinkedClients)
        {
            <option value="@item.LinkedClient.Id">@item.LinkedClient.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
}
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="@((SelectedLinkedClient != 0)? "col-md-6" : "col-md-12")">
                

<MyProject.ComponentLibrary.Profile.ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent ClientId="ClientId" GoToNextEvent="GoToNext" LoadProfileProgress="DoNothing"></MyProject.ComponentLibrary.Profile.ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent>
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @if (SelectedLinkedClient != 0)
                    {
                    

<MyProject.ComponentLibrary.Profile.ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent ClientId="SelectedLinkedClient" GoToNextEvent="GoToNext" LoadProfileProgress="DoNothing"></MyProject.ComponentLibrary.Profile.ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Change method code

```
public void ChangeLinkedClient(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedLinkedClient = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

> I am rendering this component in an MVC Core project inside a view.

Comment: Can you show us `ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent` as at first glance that is where the problem lies.  There are a few other issues with your code, but that should affect `ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent` refereshing with `ClientId="SelectedLinkedClient"`.

Comment: that component has a lot of code and would not be possible to copy full component here, however, I can add one more thing that the OnInitialized method is not triggered, if it helps, can you identfy other issues as well?

Comment: I ask because your problem is almost certainly in `ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent `. "OnInitialized method is not triggered" is a bit of a clue.  `OnInitialized` only gets called when the component is "initialised" after that only `SetParameters` and `SetParametersAsync` are called.  You probable need your code that loads the data in one of those with a checker to see if the "reference ID" of the record has changed and only reload the data if it has.

Comment: Can you give the sample code how to do that?

Comment: You should try adding a `@key=SelectedLinkedClient` to the markup for `ProfilePrimaryDetailsComponent ` so that the system knows the component needs to be replaced.

Comment: That helped, thank you very much @MrCakaShaunCurtis really appreciate.

Comment: @Jameel Hussain You OK now or do you still want some same code?

Comment: no @MrCakaShaunCurtis, your comment was helpful that I voted up, thank you

Comment: @MisterMagoo You're my saviour. It fixed a dropdown bug, where selecting a value which removes that item from a table, but the dropdown from the item below gets the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use @key to control the preservation of elements and components :

```
<option value="@item.LinkedClient.Id" @key="@item">@item.LinkedClient.Name</option>
```

You can also use @key to preserve an element or component subtree when an object doesn't change